# Printing out reals in a table with a specified number of digits

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting, precision-and-accuracy

I would like to print out an list of reals in a table with perfectly identical number of digits so that they can be perfectly right-aligned. However, once I convert them to strings, `TableForm` no longer prints them in a column:

```
  TableForm[RandomReal[1, 20], TableAlignments -> Right]
  TableForm[NumberForm[RandomReal[1, 20], {5, 3}], TableAlignments -> Right]
```

The first output has an inconsistent number of digits. The second is horizontal.
Is there a good workaround for this issue?

Comment: [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) is not [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NumberForm[#, {5, 3}] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20] // TableForm
```

Comment: Can you explain structure of this? What kind of object does TableForm return and why does NumberForm apply to it?

Comment: `...// TableForm` is equivalent to `TableForm[...]`